# JAVA code for printing with epson-tmt81

Tags: java

```
public class Test1{
    JTable jTable1;
    Test1(){
        String columns[] = new String[] {"Name","Quantity","Rate","Amount"};
        Object data[][]={
        {"PEN","10","5","50"},
        {"PENCIL","10","3","30"},
        {"KEYBOARD AND MOUSE","10","3","30"}
        };
        jTable1 = new JTable(new ExampleTableModel(data,columns));
    }
    public static void main(String h[]){
        Test1 t=new Test1();
        t.printThisBill();
    }
    public void printThisBill() {
        TableModel mod = jTable1.getModel();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date();
        String Date = dateFormat.format(date);
        String Time = timeFormat.format(date);

        double tax=0,amt1=0;
        String Header = 
        "   ****Super Market****       \n"
        + "Date: "+Date+"     Time: "+Time+"\n"
        + "---------------------------------\n"
        + "Name          Qty    Rate     Amt\n"
        + "---------------------------------\n";
        String bill = Header;
        int i =0;
        do{
            String name =     ""+ mod.getValueAt(i, 0);
            String qty =      ""+mod.getValueAt(i, 1);
            String rate =     ""+mod.getValueAt(i, 2);
            String amount =   ""+mod.getValueAt(i, 3);  
            if(name.length() > 15){
                name = name.substring(0, 15)+"  ";
            }   
            rate = rate;
            //String items = name+"\t"+qty+"\t"+rate+"\t"+amount+"\n";
            String items = name+"\t"+qty+"\t"+rate+"\t"+amount+"\n";
            bill = bill+ items;
            amt1=Double.parseDouble(amount)+amt1;
            i++;
        }while(i <= mod.getRowCount()-1);

        String amt=    "\n \n \nTotal Amount = "+amt1+"\n"
        + "Tax ="+tax+ "\n"
        + "*********************************\n"
        + "Thank you. \n";
        bill = bill+amt;
        System.out.println(bill);
        printCard(bill);
        //dispose();
    }
    public static void printCard(final String bill ){
        Printable contentToPrint = new Printable(){
            @Override
            public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int page) throws PrinterException {
                if (page > 0) {
                    return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                }
                pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics.create();
                g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
                g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
                g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(),      pageFormat.getImageableX());
                g2d.drawString(bill, 0, 0); 
                return PAGE_EXISTS;
            }   
        };

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(contentToPrint);
        try {
            job.print();
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }   
}
```

I am using EPSON TM-81 printer.
I try to print table data througth above java code it give me some error.
When i try to run this code i get message "Printer is not accepting job".
If u have any sujestion then post

Answer (score 1):

This is an receipt printer. Normally you cannot print with Java print API to that printers. You can test to print directly to the printer port with Java file i/o:

```
File windows_pr = new File("LPR:");

File linux_pr = new File("/dev/ttyS2");
```

or with general purpose (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaPOS) or vendor specific Java libraries.

Comment: Can i get example i am searching but not getting usefull example

Comment: There is some stuff from Epson about JavaPOS. Try here http://download.epson-biz.com/

Comment: I download but it is patch please check with https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/download.php?fid=4139